# if else for ant script

Tags: xml, ant

hi current i have this ant script:

```
        <target name="Cleanup Snapshots" description="Cleanup TrueCM snapshots">
        <echo>Executing: ${TrueCM_App}\ssremove.exe  -h${TrueCM_Host} "${TrueCM_New_SS}"</echo>
        <exec executable="${TrueCM_App}\ssremove.exe"   failonerror="${TrueCM_Failon_Exec}">
            <arg line="-h ${TrueCM_Host}"/>
            <arg line='-f "${TrueSASE}/${Product_version}/${name}"'/>
        </exec>


    </target>
```

what this script does is that it will execute ssremove.exe with some parameters as shown.

however, this script above is only valid when the parameter ${Product_version} contains the word "Extensions" for example 6.00_Extensions

Else if they dont contain "Extensions" the script should look like this:

```
    <target name="Cleanup Snapshots" description="Cleanup TrueCM snapshots">
        <echo>Executing: ${TrueCM_App}\ssremove.exe  -h${TrueCM_Host} "${TrueCM_New_SS}"</echo>
        <exec executable="${TrueCM_App}\ssremove.exe"   failonerror="${TrueCM_Failon_Exec}">
            <arg line="-h ${TrueCM_Host}"/>
            <arg line='-f "${TrueSASE}/${name}"'/>
        </exec>


    </target>
```

so my question is how should i add the if else statements that contain exactly the line "Extensions"? or how do i check if "Extensions" word is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to outline a solution if you can't add a custom library to your Ant build. Note that you need a pretty recent version of Ant (>= 1.7, I think).

First, you need to put the result of the test in a property (use a [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) with [contains](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html); see the [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)). Then you can use that property in `exec` to skip it when the property is `true`.

```
<condition property="hasExtensions">
    <contains string="${Product_version}" substring="Extensions">
</condition>

<exec ... unless="hasExtensions">
    ...
</exec>
```

Comment: @aaron how do i check Ant version?

Comment: I'm not sure when `condition` was added. That *might* be too old. Paste my code into the `build.xml` and run it. Ant will complain if it doesn't understand.

Comment: another question.. for this `unless="hasExtensions"` this is only applied for the case in which ${Product_version} does not contain "Extensions"? how about the one which contains "Extensions"?

Comment: Create a second property which is the negation of `hasExtensions` (say, `withoutExtensions`) and create a second `exec` target which is run `unless="withoutExtensions"`. Only one of them will be executed.

Answer (score 6):

There is an ant library : antlib ( http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net)

which supports if/else statements ( http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

Examples from the site:

```
<if>
 <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2="bar" />
 <then>
   <echo message="The value of property foo is bar" />
 </then>
 <else>
   <echo message="The value of property foo is not bar" />
 </else>
</if>


<if>
 <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2="bar" />
 <then>
   <echo message="The value of property foo is 'bar'" />
 </then>

 <elseif>
  <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2="foo" />
  <then>
   <echo message="The value of property foo is 'foo'" />
  </then>
 </elseif>


 <else>
   <echo message="The value of property foo is not 'foo' or 'bar'" />
 </else>
</if>
```

Comment: There are solutions which work with pure ANT but they are hard to understand; this is much more simple and straightforward if you can add custom libraries.